# How to write a plural form of 'ex' (ex girlfriend..etc)

Tags: nouns, plural-forms, spelling

> She's my ex

But then,

> In my photo album, you see many exes/exs/ex's of mine?

Comment: This could be a question that has opinionated answers from native speakers!    :-)

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_My_Ex%27s_Live_in_Texas

Comment: Both sexes have exes :)

Comment: My girlfriend broke up with me because we couldn't agree on how to spell "exes".

Comment: I'd quite like it to be *exen* like *oxen*. But it's not.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

We form the plurals of regular nouns ending in the sound /s/ by adding the sound /ɪz/ to the word. So for the word *bus*, /bʌs/, we get the plural form /bʌsɪz/. In writing we represent this with the written suffix -ES. So we write the plural form of *bus* as *buses*.

Words that end with the  written letter X usually end with an /s/ sound. The word *box*, for example is pronounced /bɒks/. So we pronounce the plural form of *box* as /bɒksɪz/. In the writing we add the -ES ending: *boxes*.

The word *ex* is a regular, normal noun in English. The singular is pronounced /eks/ and written *ex*. The plural is pronounced /eksɪz/ and written *exes*.

---

<sup>**Grammar note:**</sup>

<sup>1. Some nouns in English are irregular. The word *mouse* ends in an /s/ sound, but it has an irregular plural, /maɪs/, written like this: *mice*.</sup>

<sup>2. If a noun ending in an /s/ sound has the letters SE at the end, then we still add /ɪz/ to the pronunciation, but we only add S to make the written plural. We don't add ES. For example, the plural of *horse* is *horses*, not <s>*horsees*</s>.</sup>

Comment: Unless you are 5, in which case it's _horsies_ .

Comment: @aslum +1 Very nice. Touché!

Comment: A well known example of which is "all my exes live in Texas".

Comment: @EricMcCormick - but that well known example spells it with an apostrophe: [All my ex's live in Texas](http://www.countryweekly.com/news/new-george-strait-hits-collection)

Comment: I think the second grammar note should point out that although we don’t add *-es*, we **do** add the sound /ɪz/ to the word. It’s just that the silent *e* on the end of *horse* means we only need to add *-s* to achieve that sound.

Comment: @Johnny ex comes from Latin. Maybe they decided to treat it as indeclinable and thus avoid applying the English plural rule.

Comment: @KRyan Quite right. Thanks! Is that better? (see edited version)

Comment: @Johnny How would you shorten "All my exgirlfriend's exboyfriends access axes", "All my exgirlfriends' exboyfriends access axes" or "All my exgirlfriend's relatives access axes"?

Comment: Just to complete(?) the confusion, that irregularity is irregular. It's mouse/mice and louse/lice, but the plural of grouse (a game bird) is ... grouse. And "he's got a lot of grouses" is not incorrect, but that's grouse in the other sense (i.e. complaints).

Comment: @nigel222 Yes, indeed!

Comment: @Crowley “All my ex's exes access axes”, “All my exes' exes access axes”, “All my ex's relatives access axes”.

Comment: I wouldn't have used "buses", since it can be confusing given it's also spelled "busses"...

Comment: Weak vowel merger speakers will add /əz/ instead.

Comment: @matty Quite so. (I would include that kind of info on an [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/325651/adeles-pronunciation-cant-recognise-some-sounds-in-rolling-in-the-deep/325937#325937) answer btw, but want to keep the one here straightforward).  I've included the link to ELU because you seem to know a bit about English phonology and I though that site might interest you! : )

Answer (score 13):

Ex is not an abbreviation nor an acronym. There is no reason not to follow the pluralization rule of English words.

If words end in "sh", "ch", "s", "x" and "z", we are supposed to add "-es" at the end except for some exceptions.

I have checked Oxford Online Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, and Collins Online Dictionary, but none of them listed the plural from of the word. I suspect the reason is it follows the pluralization rule.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ex) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(relationship)) show that its plural form is "[exes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exes#English)".

Comment: Snap! (see my answer). The reason the plural is not listed in the dictionary is that the dictionary only lists irregular plurals. Because this word is completely regular, the dictionary does not need to list the plural. :-) +1 from me.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to say this formally is to say it like:

> I saw my **ex-boyfriend** at the mall yesterday.

In plural,

> The **ex-policemen** were on a strike demanding justice.

or,

> All of my **ex-husbands** showed up at my latest wedding!

In informal English, especially US English, it is acceptable to say:

> Hey man! I saw your **ex** with this hot dude yesterday!

or,

> She is still in touch with all of her ***exes***.

Comment: Nice answer. I'm not sure *ex* can refer to an ex-policeman though. We usually only use it to talk about ex-partners (girlfriends, boyfriends, husbands, wives).

Comment: @Araucaria It is more frequently used for ex--partners but at least as per Cambridge Dictionary, it can be used to "show that someone is no longer what they were": https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ex?q=ex-#translations

Comment: Yes, it can be used like that as a prefix, for sure. But as a word on its own, we only really use it for partners :)

Comment: This answer is correct. If you look at this page, second definition and ask for more example sentences, it uses 'exes' in one example. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ex

Answer (score 5):

Very relevant excerpt from Garner's Modern English Usage (2016):

> **ex** (*n*.) is a casualism in the sense of a former spouse or lover
>
> The plural of *ex* is *exes*, and the possessive is *ex's* — but be
>   aware that many readers will find these forms odd-looking.

[Wiktionary](http://findwords.info/term/exes) also says it's *exes*:

> **exes** (*n.*) (plural of *ex* English) vb. (en-third-person singular of: ex)

And so does [WordHippo](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/ex.html) (a site I had never run across until researching this question):

> What's the plural form of *ex*? Here's the word you're looking for.
>
> `Answer`
>
> The plural form of *ex* is **exes**.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:
If you want to appear "properly informed" for what passes for the moment as educated,  use *exes* (no matter how funny it looks<sup>1</sup>). Otherwise, feel free to use *ex's*. Just don't get it confused with the possessive of the singular *ex*, which is also *ex's*.

---

If only English were/was (take your pick)  so easy...then the plural of the two letter word *ox* would be *oxes*, for everyone.

Yours (or, for some,  *your's*)  is a great question, since the word *ex* meaning *ex-girlfriend* is a detached prefix. It looks weird standing there so  alone, so short,  ending with *-x*, added to words with the hyphen   attached: *ex-girlfriend*, *ex-convict*.

*Ex* is also the "name" of the letter *X*, and people don't agree how to  pluralize letters. Answers to the  ELU question *[What is the proper way to write the plural of a single letter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25277/what-is-the-proper-way-to-write-the-plural-of-a-single-letter-another-apostrop)* return mixed results.  Yet, if one decides that the plural of *x* is *x's*, it's not unreasonable to intuit that the plural of *ex* is *ex's*.

This plural-marking apostrophe carries over to other short words. What's the plural of *and*? Is it  *ands* or *and's*? You will find plenty  of the latter in the idiom *[no if's and's or but's](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=IHQ7V8nZJMfWmAH51JL4BA&q=no+if%27s+and%27s+but%27s&oq=no+if%27s+and%27s+but%27s&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.12...10668.32829.0.36245.25.24.0.1.1.0.475.3980.0j19j2j1j1.23.0....0...1c.1j4.64.mobile-gws-serp..2.8.1301.3..0j41j0i13j30i10.RpjN1NVGj74)*, spelled like that, the apostrophe indicating plural.

Sure, there are rules devised by grammarians, but these are the same people who brought you  such damnable rules as don't start a sentence with *and* or end one  with a preposition.

Most native speakers do not intuitively know how to pluralize *ex*. There are plenty of examples of pluralizing it as *ex's*: for example, see the reference to the hit single "All My  Ex's Live in Texas" below.

This doubt carries over to certain words that end in *-ex*. You'll find plenty of *T-Rex's* running around.

And this is not limited to *ex*. People, native speakers, tend to reach for the apostrophe when in doubt. Sometimes last names are pluralized with an apostrophe: the *Jackson's*. (And no one can authoritatively say it's wrong to do so.) Two hundred years ago, the apostrophe was used to pluralize  "foreign-sounding" words ending with a vowel: *pasta's, potato's, ouzo's* (for a reference on this, see the  next link). Now if a grocer uses *potato's* or *banana's* he's accused of using the dreadful [greengrocers’ apostrophe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Greengrocers.27_apostropheshas).

In any case,  the writer of the hit single "[All My Ex's Live in Texas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_My_Ex%27s_Live_in_Texas)"  made a stylistic choice (consciously or not), and I'm not sure that this spelling (*ex's*)  was necessarily done out of ignorance of "standard" pluralization rules; or whether it was chosen as an assertion of an alternative spelling or just because it looked better.

Apparently the author of this tweet was using their/his (take your pick) noggin:

> [#ifwedate dont bring up ya old hoes or ex's i'll smoove cut you off as fast as pnd posted that pic with kehlani in his bed](https://mobile.twitter.com/blvcksoulo/status/714799194607726592)

Notice how careful 'brown boy' was  to pluralize *ho* as *hoes*, but good luck determining if that's "correct." *Hos* has a history.

My answer is that it depends. Why shouldn't it be? This ELU site & ELL usually eschew prescriptivist answers. And if you can take your pick in the case of other uses, why can't you take your pick in the case of your ex's/exes? As usual, you should choose the Style Guide of your choice whether that's Strunk & White  or Shafer & Strait. If English speakers acted in accord,  it would be *oxes*; we've had over a millennium to conform this beast to 
the  norm.

Last thought: perhaps it should be *ices*, given that *ex* is from the Latin and the traditional plural of *codex* is *codices*, *index* is *indices*, *etc*. Many might feel *ices* to be quite an appropriate plural for *ex*.

---

<sup>1 "The plural of ex is exes, and the possessive is ex's—but be aware that many readers will find these forms odd-looking." (*The Oxford Dictionary of American Usage and Style*)</sup>

Comment: If you can find just one style guide which explicitly explains how to pluralize "ex" or its equivalent, I would be very much surprised. Extra is also a prefix and broadly used as such, e.g., extraterrestrial, extra-curriculum, extraordinary, etc. and how do you pluralize it when it is used as a noun? Is it Extra's? Even though the word is informal, ex is an English word listed in all the dictionaries (that I can find) and it follows the pluralization rule and has nothing to do with how to pluralize an English letter or English acronym.

Comment: I'm curious about the source of the assertion that the plurals of "foreign-sounding" words took an apostrophe two hundred years ago.

Comment: As for the main topic of this question, I suppose the fact that someone asked the question at all (rather than just writing the word in whatever way seemed OK to them) is a good indication that the answer to their question is _exes._ [No ifs, ands, or buts about it.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=no+ifs+ands+buts) :-)

Comment: The name of the letter "X" is ex, and its plural is exes. The name of the letter "M" is em, and its plural is ems.

Answer (score -1):

I would simply pluralize the other word and thus have the quite common sounding:

- my ex-boyfriends
- there are many of my ex-boyfriends in the picture
- those men there were all ex-boyfriends of mine.

Comment: This is a good workaround, but it doesn't really answer the O.P.'s question.

Comment: See [Scott Pilgrim](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0446029/) to know the semantic difference between “ex-boyfriends” and “exes”: the former implies that all of them are male, which the latter doesn't.